# Recoding row by index if condition is met

Tags: r

Good afternoon,

I have a problem for which I can´t seem to find a solution.

If a variable in my data equals 1, I want the row before each occurence of 1 to be recoded to 2. I tried multiple combinations of for loops and if statements, but none of them seem to work. Just as example, my current attempt:

```
for (i in nrow(df.temp$pid)) {  
  if (with(df.temp[i, ], gainloss == 1)) {
    df.temp[r, "gainloss"] <- df.temp[r - 1L, "2"]
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any better ideas? Optimally, it is easy to adjust the number rows before each occurence being recoded.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you share a sample of your dataset along with the expected output?

Comment: ```pid <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)
gainloss <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)
df.temp <- as.data.frame(cbind(gainloss, pid))
gainloss.expected.output <- c(0,0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0)```

Is an example dataset with an example expected output.

Comment: Within your code:
- i has to iterate through something, you are giving it a single value:
for (i in 2:nrow(df.temp$pid)){}.

Additionally, you could the following expression.
if(df.temp[i,"gainloss"] == 1){
      df.temp[i-1,"gainloss"] <- 2}

Now, there was an answer below which is easier and I would suggest you use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this directly without any loop. Try :

```
df.temp$gainloss[which(df.temp$gainloss == 1) - 1] <- 2
```

The above will work directly if there is no 1 in the first row. If there is a chance that I can occur in the first row, you need to remove that entry which can be done using.

```
inds <- which(df.temp$gainloss == 1) 
df.temp$gainloss[inds[inds > 1] - 1] <- 2
```

Comment: This works, thanks! How would I adapt that so that it also does not recode the last entry of pp1 when the first entry of pp2 is a 1?

Comment: @Max What is `pp1` and `pp2` ?

Comment: Participant 1, Participant 2. If the first score of Participant 2 = 1, I don´t want to change the scores of participant 1. 

I also ran into a problem with trying to generalise your approach. If I want to recode both the value before and the value 2 rows before, I cannot do that. I tried ```df.temp$gainloss[which(df.temp$gainloss == 1) - 1:2] <- 2```
and similar approaches, but to no avail.